# Facebook graph API to get statuses

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook graph API to get my most popular statuses as determined by the number of likes and comments that they have received. My code is as follows:

```
$feed = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/statuses?access_token='.$access_token.'';

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $feed);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curlout = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = json_decode($curlout, true);
$numba = count($response);

print_r($response);
```

When I try to print out the contents of the array, it says that the array is empty. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is returning an empty array?

Thanks,

Lance

Comment: Print `$curlout` and paste here.

Comment: Is your access token still valid?

Comment: Are you generating a user or appplication access token?

Comment: application access token. why? how do i go about editing the access token permissions?